# How to find the altitude of a location?

Tags: android

I am using Location class to find latitude,longitude and altitude. But I am always getting 0.0 for altitude. I have tried running the application in both emulator and real android device but still I am getting 0.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of people are having similar issues with this and has even been reported as a possible [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24809). I wouldn't be surprised if the emulator simply doesn't support it at this time. You'll probably have to work with a real device.

On real device check this...

```
locationProvider.hasAltitude();
```

Comment: hasAltitude() returns true if fix contains altitude information, false otherwise. Try install on your phone some other gps app and see if works there.